# RApache server downloads *.rhtml files, instead of execute it

Tags: r, handler, rapache, rhtml

I'm developing an R web application using RApache.

I have finished all the application and it runs correctly in my local server. But I have a problem when I port it to the university's server: the .rhtml files, where are the R-scripts; are downloaded by the browser when I tryed to open directly with a link. I think that I need to add some handler to the configuration file in order to execute this files instead of downloading (in my local server I didn't need it) but I have searched with no success.

Anybody can tell me the handler or what to do? THANKS!

Comment: Is the RApache module installed and enabled on the university server? If not, the Apache there will not know how to serve the request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a Directory directive which indicates that your R scripts which are located at the specified directory will be passed on to brew and the result will be shown in your browser instead of the html file itself.
This is done by adding in apache2.conf the following directive where you change /var/www/brew with the directory where your R scripts are located at your server

```
<Directory /var/www/brew>
    SetHandler r-script
    RHandler brew::brew
</Directory>
```